# How to convert image icon in jlabel to byte without using filechooser

Tags: java, jlabel, imageicon

I'm just new at java development, i can insert image into database by using file chooser and then convert to byte,the problem is i want to save a default image into database without using file chooser.I set the label with a specific image through properties.Can i convert the default image i set to label?

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  You need to convert the `Icon` from the `JLabel` to `BufferedImage`, from there you can simply pass it through the `ImageIO` API to get a `byte[]` array

```
Icon icon = null;
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
icon.paintIcon(null, g2d, 0, 0);
g2d.dispose();

try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
    ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(baos);
    try {
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", ios);
        // Set a flag to indicate that the write was successful
    } finally {
        ios.close();
    }
    byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my project part code:

```
..........
BufferedImage bfi = getBufferedImage(iconToImage(my_Jlabel.getIcon()));                   
ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(bfi, "png", bs);
byte[] byteArray = bs.toByteArray();
pstmt.setBytes(17, byteArray);
.............

 public static BufferedImage getBufferedImage(Image img){
if (img instanceof BufferedImage)
{
   return (BufferedImage) img;
}


BufferedImage bimage = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), 
                img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);


Graphics2D bGr = bimage.createGraphics();
bGr.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
bGr.dispose();

return bimage;
} 


static Image iconToImage(Icon icon) {    
if (icon instanceof ImageIcon) {
return ((ImageIcon)icon).getImage();
} 
else {
int w = icon.getIconWidth();
int h = icon.getIconHeight();
GraphicsEnvironment ge = 
    GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
  GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
  GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
  BufferedImage image = gc.createCompatibleImage(w, h);
  Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
  icon.paintIcon(null, g, 0, 0);
  g.dispose();
  return image;
}
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.